# Html5 Boilerplate Build Script

Tags: ant, html5boilerplate

I used [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) to set up a new HTML5 project.
I am trying to use [Ant Build Script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script) to optimize the files for production : minization , and all that stuff.

I followed every instructions in the [ReadMe](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script#readme), basically :

- Install JAVA JDK and WinAnt
- Go to project <del>root</del> /build and execute `ant build`

I have this error :

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Is this a file I'am supposed to write myself ? If so then I think it's weird the readme doesn't mention it at all.

**Edit** : Sorry I made a mistake in the path, I already was in the /build subfolder as specified in the readme.

**Edit2** : Also I realize now that I skipped the "Add the build script to your project" part. When I execute "git checkout -b ant-build-script" I have the error :

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

So I guess I need to set a git repo in my project first. **Is there a way to retrieve the right files without using git ?**

**Edit3** : I set up a git repo and followed the instructions, but now I have errors during the build process. The problem seems to be concat.js. The errors seem to indicate missing files, for instance :

```
[concat] C:\wamp\www\MoviesLouis\intermediate\index.html does not exist.
```

The `intermediate` folder is made by Ant build script, I have no control on it.
The build still finishes with "BUILD SUCCESSFUL".

The result is in the /publish folder, and I can see that all my javascript files are missing (except the ones in the /js/vendor folder).

Should I make a new question ?

Comment: Go to the Build subdir and execute ant there.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the file.root.page property, in your [project.properties](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/blob/master/config/project.properties#L24) to point to whatever file you want

Comment: Almost working, but the generated index.php still references the unconcatenated javascript files instead of the new concatenated one. I should probably report this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the file build.xml here: https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/blob/master/build.xml in line 3 `basedir` is `../`, and then it explains why: "one back since we're in build" it means that you have to execute from the build sub folder, not from the project's root.
Also, in runscript.bat https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/blob/master/runbuildscript.bat it says: "If you're on a mac or linux, just run `ant build` from this folder in Terminal", where "this folder" is again the build subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

The build script wasn't working because I renamed index.html to index.php. For now I will rename it back to html every time I want to build, but I'm still looking for an automated solution.

Comment: You could try changing the project.properties or default.properties file in the build/config directory. See file.root.page directive. Set it to index.php